# undefined function sqlsrv_connect() even after installing extenssion & odbc driver

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, driver

I have read many similar posts and followed the instructions over there, I also followed the instructions on the Microsoft's official page [Install the sql server driver for php](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-the-sql-server-driver-for-php) but it still not working and even its not showing anything related to `sqlsrv` with the `phpinfo()` function. Here is what I have done so far.

1. [Install the sql server driver for php](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-the-sql-server-driver-for-php)

   - Downloaded latest driver [from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)
   - Downloaded latest 64 bit odbc driver [from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)
   - Copied `php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll` & `php_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll` files to extenssion directory `G:\Xampp_Installation\php\ext`
   - Added thread safe extensions `php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64` & `php_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64` to the php.ini file which is under php directory.
2. Restarted Apache server.
3. Even tried with restarting machine

Environment information

- Windows 10 64 bit
- Xampp control panel v 3.2.4
- PHP version 7.4.10
- Xampp installation directory `G:\Xampp_Installation`
- php.ini file path `G:\Xampp_Installation\php\php.ini`
- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong and how can I make it work. Thanks

**Edit:** `phpinfo()` output

```
**PHP Version 7.4.10**
System  Windows NT ITLAPTOPI7G10 10.0 build 19043 (Windows 10) AMD64
Build Date  Sep 1 2020 16:45:51
Compiler    Visual C++ 2017
Architecture    x64
Configure Command   cscript /nologo /e:jscript configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--with-pdo-oci=c:\php-snap-build\deps_aux\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-12c=c:\php-snap-build\deps_aux\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--without-analyzer" "--with-pgo"
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler
Virtual Directory Support   enabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   no value
Loaded Configuration File   G:\Xampp_Installation\php\php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files (none)
Additional .ini files parsed    (none)
PHP API 20190902
PHP Extension   20190902
Zend Extension  320190902
Zend Extension Build    API320190902,TS,VC15
PHP Extension Build API20190902,TS,VC15
Debug Build no
Thread Safety   enabled
Thread API  Windows Threads
Zend Signal Handling    disabled
Zend Memory Manager enabled
Zend Multibyte Support  provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support    enabled
DTrace Support  disabled
Registered PHP Streams  php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, zip, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, https, ftps, phar
Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp, ssl, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2, tlsv1.3
Registered Stream Filters   convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, zlib.*, bzip2.*
Zend logoThis program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

**Configuration**

```
apache2handler
Apache Version  Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.10
Apache API Version  20120211
Server Administrator    postmaster@localhost
Hostname:Port   localhost:80
Max Requests    Per Child: 0 - Keep Alive: on - Max Per Connection: 100
Timeouts    Connection: 300 - Keep-Alive: 5
Virtual Server  No
Server Root G:/Xampp_Installation/apache
Loaded Modules  core mod_win32 mpm_winnt http_core mod_so mod_access_compat mod_actions mod_alias mod_allowmethods mod_asis mod_auth_basic mod_authn_core mod_authn_file mod_authz_core mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_cgi mod_dav_lock mod_dir mod_env mod_headers mod_include mod_info mod_isapi mod_log_config mod_cache_disk mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_proxy mod_proxy_ajp mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_socache_shmcb mod_ssl mod_status mod_version mod_php7
Directive   Local Value Master Value
engine  1   1
last_modified   0   0
xbithack    0   0
```

**Apache Environment**

```
Variable    Value
MIBDIRS G:/Xampp_Installation/php/extras/mibs
MYSQL_HOME  \xampp\mysql\bin
OPENSSL_CONF    G:/Xampp_Installation/apache/bin/openssl.cnf
PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR    \xampp\php
PHPRC   \xampp\php
TMP \xampp\tmp
HTTP_HOST   localhost
HTTP_CONNECTION keep-alive
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL  max-age=0
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS  1
HTTP_USER_AGENT Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
HTTP_ACCEPT text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE none
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE navigate
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER ?1
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST document
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    gzip, deflate, br
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    en-US,en;q=0.9
PATH    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
SystemRoot  C:\Windows
COMSPEC C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
PATHEXT .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
WINDIR  C:\Windows
SERVER_SIGNATURE    <address>Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.10 Server at localhost Port 80</address>
SERVER_SOFTWARE Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.10
SERVER_NAME localhost
SERVER_ADDR ::1
SERVER_PORT 80
REMOTE_ADDR ::1
DOCUMENT_ROOT   G:/Xampp_Installation/htdocs
REQUEST_SCHEME  http
CONTEXT_PREFIX  no value
CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT   G:/Xampp_Installation/htdocs
SERVER_ADMIN    postmaster@localhost
SCRIPT_FILENAME G:/Xampp_Installation/htdocs/VillageAutomation/GetAllData.php
REMOTE_PORT 61839
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL HTTP/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD  GET
QUERY_STRING    no value
REQUEST_URI /VillageAutomation/GetAllData.php
SCRIPT_NAME /VillageAutomation/GetAllData.php
```

**HTTP Headers Information**

```
HTTP Request Headers
HTTP Request    GET /VillageAutomation/GetAllData.php HTTP/1.1
Host    localhost
Connection  keep-alive
Cache-Control   max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests   1
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site  none
Sec-Fetch-Mode  navigate
Sec-Fetch-User  ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest  document
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.9
HTTP Response Headers
X-Powered-By    PHP/7.4.10
```

**bcmath**

```
BCMath support  enabled
Directive   Local Value Master Value
bcmath.scale    0   0
```

**bz2**

```
BZip2 Support   Enabled
Stream Wrapper support  compress.bzip2://
Stream Filter support   bzip2.decompress, bzip2.compress
BZip2 Version   1.0.8, 13-Jul-2019
```

**calendar**

```
Calendar support    enabled
```

**Core**

```
PHP Version 7.4.10
Directive   Local Value Master Value
allow_url_fopen On  On
allow_url_include   Off Off
arg_separator.input &   &
arg_separator.output    &   &
auto_append_file    no value    no value
auto_globals_jit    On  On
auto_prepend_file   no value    no value
browscap    G:\Xampp_Installation\php\extras\browscap.ini   G:\Xampp_Installation\php\extras\browscap.ini
default_charset UTF-8   UTF-8
default_mimetype    text/html   text/html
disable_classes no value    no value
disable_functions   no value    no value
display_errors  On  On
display_startup_errors  On  On
doc_root    no value    no value
docref_ext  no value    no value
docref_root no value    no value
enable_dl   Off Off
enable_post_data_reading    On  On
error_append_string no value    no value
error_log   G:\Xampp_Installation\php\logs\php_error_log    G:\Xampp_Installation\php\logs\php_error_log
error_prepend_string    no value    no value
error_reporting 22527   22527
expose_php  On  On
extension_dir   G:\Xampp_Installation\php\ext   G:\Xampp_Installation\php\ext
file_uploads    On  On
hard_timeout    2   2
highlight.comment   #FF8000 #FF8000
highlight.default   #0000BB #0000BB
highlight.html  #000000 #000000
highlight.keyword   #007700 #007700
highlight.string    #DD0000 #DD0000
html_errors On  On
ignore_repeated_errors  Off Off
ignore_repeated_source  Off Off
ignore_user_abort   Off Off
implicit_flush  Off Off
include_path    G:\Xampp_Installation\php\PEAR  G:\Xampp_Installation\php\PEAR
input_encoding  no value    no value
internal_encoding   no value    no value
log_errors  On  On
log_errors_max_len  1024    1024
mail.add_x_header   Off Off
mail.force_extra_parameters no value    no value
mail.log    no value    no value
max_execution_time  1300    1300
max_file_uploads    20  20
max_input_nesting_level 64  64
max_input_time  60  60
max_input_vars  1000    1000
memory_limit    1000M   1000M
open_basedir    no value    no value
output_buffering    4096    4096
output_encoding no value    no value
output_handler  no value    no value
post_max_size   1000M   1000M
precision   14  14
realpath_cache_size 4096K   4096K
realpath_cache_ttl  120 120
register_argc_argv  Off Off
report_memleaks On  On
report_zend_debug   On  On
request_order   GP  GP
sendmail_from   no value    no value
sendmail_path   no value    no value
serialize_precision -1  -1
short_open_tag  Off Off
SMTP    localhost   localhost
smtp_port   25  25
sys_temp_dir    no value    no value
syslog.facility LOG_USER    LOG_USER
syslog.filter   no-ctrl no-ctrl
syslog.ident    php php
track_errors    Off Off
unserialize_callback_func   no value    no value
upload_max_filesize 1000M   1000M
upload_tmp_dir  G:\Xampp_Installation\tmp   G:\Xampp_Installation\tmp
user_dir    no value    no value
user_ini.cache_ttl  300 300
user_ini.filename   .user.ini   .user.ini
variables_order GPCS    GPCS
windows.show_crt_warning    Off Off
xmlrpc_error_number 0   0
xmlrpc_errors   Off Off
zend.assertions 1   1
zend.detect_unicode On  On
zend.enable_gc  On  On
zend.exception_ignore_args  Off Off
zend.multibyte  Off Off
zend.script_encoding    no value    no value
```

**ctype**

```
ctype functions enabled
```

**curl**

```
cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    7.70.0
Age 6
Features
AsynchDNS   Yes
CharConv    No
Debug   No
GSS-Negotiate   No
IDN Yes
IPv6    Yes
krb4    No
Largefile   Yes
libz    Yes
NTLM    Yes
NTLMWB  No
SPNEGO  Yes
SSL Yes
SSPI    Yes
TLS-SRP No
HTTP2   Yes
GSSAPI  No
KERBEROS5   Yes
UNIX_SOCKETS    Yes
PSL No
HTTPS_PROXY Yes
MULTI_SSL   No
BROTLI  No
Protocols   dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smb, smbs, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host    x86_64-pc-win32
SSL Version OpenSSL/1.1.1g
ZLib Version    1.2.11
libSSH Version  libssh2/1.9.0
Directive   Local Value Master Value
curl.cainfo G:\Xampp_Installation\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt G:\Xampp_Installation\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

**date**

```
date/time support   enabled
timelib version 2018.03
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   2020.1
Timezone Database   internal
Default timezone    Europe/Berlin
Directive   Local Value Master Value
date.default_latitude   31.7667 31.7667
date.default_longitude  35.2333 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith 90.583333   90.583333
date.sunset_zenith  90.583333   90.583333
date.timezone   Europe/Berlin   Europe/Berlin
```

**dom & other**

```
DOM/XML enabled
DOM/XML API Version 20031129
libxml Version  2.9.10
HTML Support    enabled
XPath Support   enabled
XPointer Support    enabled
Schema Support  enabled
RelaxNG Support enabled
exif
EXIF Support    enabled
Supported EXIF Version  0220
Supported filetypes JPEG, TIFF
Multibyte decoding support using mbstring   enabled
Extended EXIF tag formats   Canon, Casio, Fujifilm, Nikon, Olympus, Samsung, Panasonic, DJI, Sony, Pentax, Minolta, Sigma, Foveon, Kyocera, Ricoh, AGFA, Epson
Directive   Local Value Master Value
exif.decode_jis_intel   JIS JIS
exif.decode_jis_motorola    JIS JIS
exif.decode_unicode_intel   UCS-2LE UCS-2LE
exif.decode_unicode_motorola    UCS-2BE UCS-2BE
exif.encode_jis no value    no value
exif.encode_unicode ISO-8859-15 ISO-8859-15
fileinfo
fileinfo support    enabled
libmagic    537
filter
Input Validation and Filtering  enabled
Directive   Local Value Master Value
filter.default  unsafe_raw  unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags    no value    no value
ftp
FTP support enabled
FTPS support    enabled
gd
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.9.1
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support    enabled
libJPEG Version 9 compatible
PNG Support enabled
libPNG Version  1.6.34
WBMP Support    enabled
XPM Support enabled
libXpm Version  30512
XBM Support enabled
WebP Support    enabled
BMP Support enabled
TGA Read Support    enabled
Directive   Local Value Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning  1   1
gettext
GetText Support enabled
hash
hash support    enabled
Hashing Engines md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224 sha256 sha384 sha512/224 sha512/256 sha512 sha3-224 sha3-256 sha3-384 sha3-512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru snefru256 gost gost-crypto adler32 crc32 crc32b crc32c fnv132 fnv1a32 fnv164 fnv1a64 joaat haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5
MHASH support   Enabled
MHASH API Version   Emulated Support
iconv
iconv support   enabled
iconv implementation    "libiconv"
iconv library version   1.16
Directive   Local Value Master Value
iconv.input_encoding    no value    no value
iconv.internal_encoding no value    no value
iconv.output_encoding   no value    no value
json
json support    enabled
libxml
libXML support  active
libXML Compiled Version 2.9.10
libXML Loaded Version   20910
libXML streams  enabled
mbstring
Multibyte Support   enabled
Multibyte string engine libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation disabled
libmbfl version 1.3.2
mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.
Multibyte (japanese) regex support  enabled
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) version 6.9.4
Directive   Local Value Master Value
mbstring.detect_order   no value    no value
mbstring.encoding_translation   Off Off
mbstring.func_overload  0   0
mbstring.http_input no value    no value
mbstring.http_output    no value    no value
mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml) ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml)
mbstring.internal_encoding  no value    no value
mbstring.language   neutral neutral
mbstring.regex_retry_limit  1000000 1000000
mbstring.regex_stack_limit  100000  100000
mbstring.strict_detection   Off Off
mbstring.substitute_character   no value    no value
mysqli
MysqlI Support  enabled
Client API library version  mysqlnd 7.4.10
Active Persistent Links 0
Inactive Persistent Links   0
Active Links    0
Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysqli.allow_local_infile   Off Off
mysqli.allow_persistent On  On
mysqli.default_host no value    no value
mysqli.default_port 3306    3306
mysqli.default_pw   no value    no value
mysqli.default_socket   no value    no value
mysqli.default_user no value    no value
mysqli.max_links    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent   Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect    Off Off
mysqli.rollback_on_cached_plink Off Off
mysqlnd
mysqlnd enabled
Version mysqlnd 7.4.10
Compression supported
core SSL    supported
extended SSL    supported
Command buffer size 4096
Read buffer size    32768
Read timeout    86400
Collecting statistics   Yes
Collecting memory statistics    Yes
Tracing n/a
Loaded plugins  mysqlnd,debug_trace,auth_plugin_mysql_native_password,auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password,auth_plugin_caching_sha2_password,auth_plugin_sha256_password
API Extensions  mysqli,pdo_mysql
odbc
ODBC Support    enabled
Active Persistent Links 0
Active Links    0
ODBC library    Win32
ODBCVER 0x0350
Directive   Local Value Master Value
odbc.allow_persistent   On  On
odbc.check_persistent   On  On
odbc.default_cursortype Static cursor   Static cursor
odbc.default_db no value    no value
odbc.default_pw no value    no value
odbc.default_user   no value    no value
odbc.defaultbinmode return as is    return as is
odbc.defaultlrl return up to 4096 bytes return up to 4096 bytes
odbc.max_links  Unlimited   Unlimited
odbc.max_persistent Unlimited   Unlimited
openssl
OpenSSL support enabled
OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 1.1.1g 21 Apr 2020
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 1.1.1g 21 Apr 2020
Openssl default config  C:\Apache24\conf/openssl.cnf
Directive   Local Value Master Value
openssl.cafile  G:\Xampp_Installation\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt G:\Xampp_Installation\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt
openssl.capath  no value    no value
pcre
PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support  enabled
PCRE Library Version    10.34 2019-11-21
PCRE Unicode Version    12.1.0
PCRE JIT Support    enabled
PCRE JIT Target x86 64bit (little endian + unaligned)
Directive   Local Value Master Value
pcre.backtrack_limit    1000000 1000000
pcre.jit    1   1
pcre.recursion_limit    100000  100000
PDO
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers mysql, odbc, sqlite
pdo_mysql
PDO Driver for MySQL    enabled
Client API version  mysqlnd 7.4.10
PDO_ODBC
PDO Driver for ODBC (Win32) enabled
ODBC Connection Pooling Enabled, strict matching
pdo_sqlite
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x   enabled
SQLite Library  3.31.1
Phar
Phar: PHP Archive support   enabled
Phar API version    1.1.1
Phar-based phar archives    enabled
Tar-based phar archives enabled
ZIP-based phar archives enabled
gzip compression    enabled
bzip2 compression   enabled
OpenSSL support enabled
Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik.
Phar fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger.
Portions of tar implementation Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle.
Directive   Local Value Master Value
phar.cache_list no value    no value
phar.readonly   On  On
phar.require_hash   On  On
readline
Readline Support    enabled
Readline library    WinEditLine
Directive   Local Value Master Value
cli.pager   no value    no value
cli.prompt  \b \>   \b \> 
Reflection
Reflection  enabled
session
Session Support enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php_serialize php php_binary
Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly no value    no value
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_samesite no value    no value
session.cookie_secure   0   0
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.lazy_write  On  On
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   G:\Xampp_Installation\tmp   G:\Xampp_Installation\tmp
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.sid_bits_per_character  5   5
session.sid_length  26  26
session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On
session.upload_progress.enabled On  On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_
session.use_cookies 1   1
session.use_only_cookies    1   1
session.use_strict_mode 0   0
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
SimpleXML
SimpleXML support   enabled
Schema support  enabled
SPL
SPL support enabled
Interfaces  OuterIterator, RecursiveIterator, SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject
Classes AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException
standard
Dynamic Library Support enabled
Internal Sendmail Support for Windows   enabled
Directive   Local Value Master Value
assert.active   1   1
assert.bail 0   0
assert.callback no value    no value
assert.exception    0   0
assert.quiet_eval   0   0
assert.warning  1   1
auto_detect_line_endings    0   0
default_socket_timeout  60  60
from    no value    no value
session.trans_sid_hosts no value    no value
session.trans_sid_tags  a=href,area=href,frame=src,form=    a=href,area=href,frame=src,form=
unserialize_max_depth   4096    4096
url_rewriter.hosts  no value    no value
url_rewriter.tags   form=   form=
user_agent  no value    no value
tokenizer
Tokenizer Support   enabled
xml
XML Support active
XML Namespace Support   active
libxml2 Version 2.9.10
xmlreader
XMLReader   enabled
xmlwriter
XMLWriter   enabled
zip
Zip enabled
Zip version 1.15.6
Libzip headers version  1.5.2
Libzip library version  1.5.2
zlib
ZLib Support    enabled
Stream Wrapper  compress.zlib://
Stream Filter   zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version    1.2.11
Linked Version  1.2.11
Directive   Local Value Master Value
zlib.output_compression Off Off
zlib.output_compression_level   -1  -1
zlib.output_handler no value    no value
Additional Modules
Module Name
Environment
Variable    Value
AGSDESKTOPJAVA  C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\
ALLUSERSPROFILE C:\ProgramData
APPDATA C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming
ChocolateyInstall   C:\ProgramData\chocolatey
CommonProgramFiles  C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86) C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432  C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME    ITLAPTOPI7G10
ComSpec C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
DriverData  C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
GDAL_DATA   C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\gdal-data
JAVA_HOME   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281
LOCALAPPDATA    C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS    8
OS  Windows_NT
Path    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
PATHEXT .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
POSTGIS_ENABLE_OUTDB_RASTERS    1
POSTGIS_GDAL_ENABLED_DRIVERS    GTiff PNG JPEG GIF XYZ DTED USGSDEM AAIGrid
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE  AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER    Intel64 Family 6 Model 126 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL 6
PROCESSOR_REVISION  7e05
ProgramData C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles    C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)   C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432    C:\Program Files
PROJ_LIB    C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\share\contrib\postgis-3.1\proj
PSModulePath    C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\
PUBLIC  C:\Users\Public
SystemDrive C:
SystemRoot  C:\Windows
TEMP    C:\Windows\TEMP
TMP C:\Windows\TEMP
USERDOMAIN  WORKGROUP
USERNAME    ITLAPTOPI7G10$
USERPROFILE C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile
windir  C:\Windows
AP_PARENT_PID   15416
PHP Variables
Variable    Value
$_SERVER['MIBDIRS'] G:/Xampp_Installation/php/extras/mibs
$_SERVER['MYSQL_HOME']  \xampp\mysql\bin
$_SERVER['OPENSSL_CONF']    G:/Xampp_Installation/apache/bin/openssl.cnf
$_SERVER['PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR']    \xampp\php
$_SERVER['PHPRC']   \xampp\php
$_SERVER['TMP'] \xampp\tmp
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']   localhost
$_SERVER['HTTP_CONNECTION'] keep-alive
$_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL']  max-age=0
$_SERVER['HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS']  1
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'] text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
$_SERVER['HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE'] none
$_SERVER['HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE'] navigate
$_SERVER['HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER'] ?1
$_SERVER['HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST'] document
$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING']    gzip, deflate, br
$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']    en-US,en;q=0.9
$_SERVER['PATH']    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
$_SERVER['SystemRoot']  C:\Windows
$_SERVER['COMSPEC'] C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
$_SERVER['PATHEXT'] .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
$_SERVER['WINDIR']  C:\Windows
$_SERVER['SERVER_SIGNATURE']    <address>Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.10 Server at localhost Port 80</address>
$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.10
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] localhost
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] ::1
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] 80
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ::1
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']   G:/Xampp_Installation/htdocs
$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']  http
$_SERVER['CONTEXT_PREFIX']  no value
$_SERVER['CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT']   G:/Xampp_Installation/htdocs
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADMIN']    postmaster@localhost
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] G:/Xampp_Installation/htdocs/VillageAutomation/GetAllData.php
$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'] 61839
$_SERVER['GATEWAY_INTERFACE']   CGI/1.1
$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] HTTP/1.1
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']  GET
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']    no value
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] /VillageAutomation/GetAllData.php
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] /VillageAutomation/GetAllData.php
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']    /VillageAutomation/GetAllData.php
$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT']  1630405366.5958
$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']    1630405366
```

Comment: Did you actually install SQLServer? You dont actually say you did

Comment: Can you show output from `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: @RiggsFolly, yes I have it installed alread. Let me add the `phpinfo()` output

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Its a lot of information should I add all or specific information?